# Add vertical spacing into list of figures for each section (scrartcl)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script

I have found several posts and questions from people wanting to *remove* the vertical spacing automatically added to the list of figures, but my problem is (exactly) the opposite:

I'm using the `scrartcl` document class with sections as the highest level seperator. In my list of figures there is no separation between the figures of different sections.

*How can I add such a visual separation?*

See the following minimal working example and the output below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the mwe]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice question!

Comment: Indeed a very good question, but be aware that classes witch chapters provide this feature by default. KOMA provides its own interface with the key `listof` and values like `chaptergapline`, `chaptergapsmall` or `nochaptergap`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I'm aware that for example scrbook adds this automatically, but since I'm using scrartcl this is not the case. But a good addendum for future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to patch the `\@startsection` command; patching `\section` is also possible, but it would add a spacing command also for `\section*`. Not a big deal, but if it's possible to avoid it, the better.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@startsection}
  {\@dblarg}
  {\artemis@space@loft{#2}\@dblarg}
  {}{}
\newcommand{\artemis@space@loft}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1=\sectionnumdepth
    \doforeachtocfile[float]{%
      \addtocontents{\@currext}{\protect\addvspace{\@sectionlistsgap}}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\@sectionlistsgap}{5pt} % <-- change here the desired gap
\makeatother

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Section}

\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}

\section{Section}

\subsection{SUB}

\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{Figure}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\@dblarg` is executed only when we have `\section` without `*`; so, before TeX executes it, we add `\artemis@space@loft`, that adds a vertical space annotation in the `.lof` and `.lot` files. This is the same as the `book` class does for `\chapter` (10pt is used there, in an article a smaller space seems more appropriate). It uses a technique suggested by [Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) that exploits a feature of Koma-Script; in this way also newly defined float types will get the same treatment.

Parameter `#2` to `\@startsection` is the section level, so we check it's the same as `\sectionnumdepth`. For `article` one should use `\@ne` instead of `\sectionnumdepth` in the body of `\artemis@space@loft`.

I added `\subsection` in order to check that the spacing is added only for sections (and it is).

[image]

## Important update for KoMaScript version 3.14

When the newly released version 3.14 of KoMaScript classes and packages has been installed, the above patch doesn't work any more.

For this version one has to change

```
\patchcmd{\@startsection}
  {\@dblarg}
  {\artemis@space@loft{#2}\@dblarg}
  {}{}
```

into

```
\patchcmd{\scr@startsection}
  {\scr@section@dblarg}
  {\artemis@space@loft{#2}\scr@section@dblarg}
  {}{}
```

Thanks to Johannes_B for having noticed it so early (the new version was uploaded in TeX Live on December 8, 2014).

If both patches are necessary for a cooperative job when one of the parties has not yet updated KoMaScript, then

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\scr@startsection
  \patchcmd{\scr@startsection}
    {\scr@section@dblarg}
    {\artemis@space@loft{#2}\scr@section@dblarg}
    {}{}
\else
  \patchcmd{\@startsection}
    {\@dblarg}
    {\artemis@space@loft{#2}\@dblarg}
    {}{}
\fi
\newcommand{\artemis@space@loft}[1]{%
...
```

should do.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very nice answer, good explanation and (of course) it works nicely. :-)

Comment: @Artemis From your profile I learned you're not a TeX.SX newbie, so the welcome is late. Surely it was a very well posed question. Thanks for the contribution: your question seems to be useful.

Comment: Well, I've always had a look at tex.sx q&a when looking for solutions for problems I encountered. But since this is my first question here (so kind of a newbie), giving me a nice welcome was still appropriate.